# How to increment integers on the current line by 1

Tags: vim, nand2tetris

I'm working on nand2tetris, and I end up with a lot of files that end up looking like this:

```
Bit(in=in[0], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[1], load=load, out=out]1]);
...
Bit(in=in[15], load=load, out=out[15]);
```

So I've been yanking the first line, then using 15p, and then doing `:s/0/i/g` 15 times (where `i` is the index I need). I've noticed that I can replace this with `:s/\[\d\]/\[i\]/g`, but even here I manually set the value of `i` each time I run the command. Is there a command I can run so that `i` is automatically calculated to be `\d+1` and I can just repeat the command for each line, without manually specifying the value?

Comment: i want the answer too. but i am afraid we cannot achieve it with only regex.

Comment: You can use a substitution but you will need to use `\=`. e.g. `:s/\d\+/\=str2nr(submatch(0))+1/`. See `:h :s\=` for more information.

Comment: @PeterRincker I don't believe the str2nr is necessary.

Comment: @FDinoff Fantastic! You are correct. That really shortens it up too: `:s/\d\+/\=submatch(0)+1/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like Peter Rincker (on-the-fly macros are awesome) but here is another solution, just for the sake of it:

```
yy                         " yank current line
15p                        " paste 15 times
:,']s/0/\=line('.')-1/g    " substitute every 0 from cursor to last
                             pasted line with the current line number
```

Comment: +1 Always good to have options! Should be noted that you may need to adjust the `-1` to some other number if the code block is lower down in the file. Or you can do some more trickery like `:,']s/0/\=line('.')-line("'[")/g`.

Answer (score 7):

One method is to use a Vim macro.

**Overview**

Copy the line then paste the line. Increment both numbers.

**The macro**

```
qqyyp<c-a>l<c-a>q
```

Note this saves the macro into register `q`.

Execute the macro via `@q` or do it all together via `14@q`.

For more help see:

```
:h q
:h ctrl-a
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, you should be able to use the [increment](https://github.com/vim-scripts/increment.vim--Avadhanula) package in vim.  Take your first line of text and paste it 15 times using `15p`:

```
Bit(in=in[0], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[0], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[0], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[0], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[0], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[0], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[0], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[0], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[0], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[0], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[0], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[0], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[0], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[0], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[0], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[0], load=load, out=out[0]);
```

You can select the '0' on the first line, and enter visual block mode using Ctrl-V. Highlight to the bottom while in visual block mode, so that all of the 0s are highlighted.  Then you can type `:Inc<CR>`. This will increment the numbers, essentially numbering your lines in text:

```
Bit(in=in[ 0], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[ 1], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[ 2], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[ 3], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[ 4], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[ 5], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[ 6], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[ 7], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[ 8], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[ 9], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[10], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[11], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[12], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[13], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[14], load=load, out=out[0]);
Bit(in=in[15], load=load, out=out[0]);
```